# Woocommerce: shortcode / PHP to display current price of a variable product?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm customizing the product page of a site that will have variable products.

Currently, using the Booster for Woocommerce plugin, which gives me convenient shortcodes like *[wcj_product_regular_price]* and *[wcj_product_sale_price]*, that nicely display the regular and sale prices of the product.

Problem is, when it comes to variable products, they both show **$ 0** until variations are selected.

Is there a Woocommerce native shortcode (or a PHP code) to display the current price (or the price range) of a variable product? Like, if the product's variations range from $ 20 to $ 50, how can I display something like "This product's price ranges between {shortcode_I_don't_know}, please choose options to see the exact pricing"?

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it figured out.

Edwin's answer to use the Booster shortcode *[wcj_product_price]* (instead of *[wcj_product_regular_price]* and *[wcj_product_sale_price]*) outputs the min-max range, i.e. **$40-$80**.

For people who **don't** use Booster, there's a way to use Woocommerce's built-in variables:

```
Minimum Price: $ <?php echo ($product->get_variation_sale_price()); ?>
Maximum Price: $ <?php echo ($product->get_variation_sale_price('max')); ?>
```

Output:

- Minimum Price: $ 40.00
- Maximum Price: $ 80.00

Bonus: if you don't want the trailing zeroes, use *floatval*:

```
Minimum Price: $ <?php echo floatval(($product->get_variation_sale_price())); ?>
Maximum Price: $ <?php echo floatval(($product->get_variation_sale_price('max'))); ?>
```

Output:

- Minimum Price: $ 40
- Maximum Price: $ 80

For future reference, here are the WooCommerce native PHP variables for variable products:

```
$product->get_variation_regular_price(); // Min regular price
$product->get_variation_sale_price(); // Min sale price
$product->get_variation_price(); // Min price

$product->get_variation_regular_price('max'); // Max regular price
$product->get_variation_sale_price('max'); // Max sale price
$product->get_variation_price('max'); // Max price
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these shortcode

```php
[wcj_product_price] shortcode displays a price for WooCommerce product
```

Comment: That solves 90% of it - displays "$40-$80" as the output.